# Cannot set defaultSize after dragging the resizer of the tomkp/react-split-pane

Tags: reactjs

The splitpane is configured as follows, where I have separate buttons to set the primarySize.  Clicking on my buttons sets the primarySize which then updates the splitpane.  This is working fine.  When I drag the resizer, the Splitpane responds property. But when I click again on my buttons to set the primarySize the splitpane no longer responds.

```
const [primarySize, setPrimarySize] = useState("35%");

<SplitPane
      split="vertical"
      minSize={0}
      defaultSize={primarySize}
    >
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use "onDragFinished" event prop of SplitPane. When drag finished, you set  new position in state. When clicked default position button, set default value in state.

```
const [splitPosition, setSplitPosition] = useState("50%");

<SplitPane split="vertical" defaultSize={splitPosition} onDragFinished={(e)=>setSplitPosition(e)} ></SplitPane>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set defaultSize on event handler of dragging the resizer.

```js
const event = (e) => {
  setDefaultSize(CHANGED_VALUE);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).